# How Do You Set Leaderboard Player Stats Using The Costume Dummy In RecRoom?

Tags: rec-room

Im trying to set some stats to a leaderboard using the costume dummy in rec room. How do i do that in a way thats efficient.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want the leaderboard stat to be reversed when they take off the costume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The costume dummy has a single output pin that has the following behavior:

- When nobody is wearing the costume, it outputs -1 as a constant signal
- When a player is wearing the costume, it outputs their player ID as a constant signal

As such, setting a leaderboard stat from a costume can be as simple as connecting the costume's pin to the red and the cyan input pins of a > advanced comparator, then connecting the red output of that advanced comparator to the player ID pin of the leaderboard chip. From there, just configure the stat channel pin to be the channel you want to use (1, 2, or 3), and configure the value pin to have the value you want to be set. Make sure you configure the leaderboard chip to be in the "Set" mode.